# Packaging separate jar file to war file in maven

Tags: maven, package, war

I have created a web application using Java. According to the design, I have created a plugin for that web application. 
When I am releasing the package, I want to package that plugin's jar file in to the "WEB-INF/lib" directory. 
I am just copying the jar file manually. Instead of that, are there any capabilities to handle those things using maven? **I don't want to add that plugin in to the web application as a dependancy.**

Comment: Why not adding it as a dependency cause you want to have it in lib directory?

Comment: I added web application as a dependancy to the plugin. If I have done vise versa, there would be a cyclic dependancy. I want to overcome that also.

Comment: A web application can't be used as a dependency (We are talking about a WAR file?) ...having a cyclic dependency you need to refactor your modules...but without pom files nor a directory structure nobody can help here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify it within the maven war plugin. Please see below.

Let

jar file -> jarfile.jar

jar file path -> jarFilePath ( with reference to base dir )

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <!--jarfile.jar file in to the WEB-INF/lib folder -->
            <resource>
                <directory>jarFilePath</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>jarfile.jar</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```